# C# - Error with Method and Data Type

Tags: c#

I keep getting a compiler error that says

> The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.

It has to do with my `int` type. I've changed the data type to `int` but it is still giving me an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void btnGetPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Validator.IsPresent(txtPatientID))
    {
        this.GetPatient(txtPatientID); //add method
        if (patient == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No patient found with this ID. " + "Please    try again.", "Patient Not Found");
            this.ClearControls(); 
        }
        else
            this.DisplayPatient(); 
    }
}

private void GetPatient(int patientCode)
{
    try
    {
        patient = PatientMaintenanceDB.GetPatient(patientCode); //add method
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Convert.toInt32(txtPatientID.Text) on the line you are getting error!! Textboxes values are strings so Have to convert it into required datatype while using it as datatype other than string!

Comment: Is this a web page callback? Where is `Validator.IsPresent` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The `txtPatientID` is likely the id of a textbox not an `int`. This why you get this error. You could overcome this, parsing the value of `txtPatientID.Text`:

```
int patientId;
if(int.TryParse(txtPatientID.Text, out patientId))
{
    this.GetPatient(patientId);
    if (patient == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No patient found with this ID. " + "Please    try again.", "Patient Not Found");
         this.ClearControls(); 
    }
    else
        this.DisplayPatient(); 

}
```

Comment: You're guessing, and it's more likely to be a textbox.

Comment: @Blorgbeard oops you are bloody correct ! Thank you very much ! I just corrected it.